# (C++) Does a new declaration of an already existing object erase data?

Tags: c++, struct

I am currently programming a piece of code that heavily uses structs in c++.

I found nothing about this online, so I am asking the question here:
if I redefine an already existing object, is all data of this object erased?

My code looks something like this:

```
struct someStruct{
int someInt = 0; //some other data here
}

int main(){
   while(someCondition){
      someStruct newStruct;
      //do stuff with Struct, like:
      newStruct.someInt=1;
      //use newStruct somewhere else
   }
}
```

My question here is, whether the new declaration in the second run-through of the while loop keeps the data of the previously used object or erases it. (Do I have to delete unwanted data in newStruct or not? Is this an application of new and delete)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you redefine an already existing object in the same scope, you will get an error.
as for your code sample, each iteration is a different scope, 
thus it's the same as having the same variable name on two different functions, they are not related.

Comment: OK, Thank you! Does this also mean that I will have a memory leak in my code if I write it like that?

Comment: @SeseMueller you don't have a memory leak, just like calling a function that defines some variables, multiple times will not cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Scope of variable inside loop is only for one iteration .
In second Iteration all the variable created again 
so the previously created object will be destroyed.

Comment: So in your case every time when condition is true , a new object of structure is created